# Making sense of generic Java method header

Tags: java, generics

I was reading up on generics in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) and [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1692544), and while I understand the point of having them, I'm having a little trouble understanding the header of a generic Java method. I'm used to:

```
public returnType methodName(parameters){body}
```

What keeps confusing me is the specification of a generic method declaration:

```
public *genericType* returnType methodName(parameters){body}
```

or

```
public static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(Collection<T> c) {}
```

What is this type declaration (`<T>` between static and void) affecting? Is it just outlining the type that the method parameters can be?

Comment: It means "This method has a generic type parameter referred to as `T`"

Comment: @khelwood Why doesn't the existence of `Collection<T>` in the signature implicitly have that same meaning?

Comment: It lets you add a generic type parameter to just that method, as opposed to declaring it at the class level.

Comment: Didnt even see void there : /

Comment: @Matt What if you have more than one generic type for that method?  If they are being inferred, how would you know what order to declare them in?

Comment: @Matt Because there is nothing (other than convention) which says that you name type variables like `T`. For example, you could write `void foo(Collection<String> strs) { String bar = ""; }` (which compiles), but you could also write `<String> void foo(Collection<String> strs) { String bar = ""; }` which does not, since `String` is a type variable, not `java.util.String`. Similarly, if it were inferrable that `T` might mean a type variable, there is no way of knowing whether you mean that or some class which you forgot to import, `T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<T>` between `static` and `void` in this case means "There is a generic type parameter being referred to as `T` in this method."

Compare case 1:

```
class Foo<T> {
     public void doFoo(Collection<T> items) ...
}
```

with case 2:

```
class Foo {
    public <T> void doFoo(Collection<T> items) ...
}
```

and case 3:

```
class Foo {
    public void doFoo(Collection<T> items) ...
}
```

In the first case, `T` is a generic type for the whole class, so if you call `doFoo`, the `<T>` in the collection you pass in needs to be the same `T` as the generic type of the instance of `Foo<T>`.

In the second case, `T` is a generic type existing only in the method `doFoo`.

In case 3, `T` must be an actual type, because there is no declaration that it is a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The `<T>` declared as return type references the `<T>` declared in the parameter. That way you know that if you feed your method a collection of Strings, you'll get a String as a result.

So in conclusion, a generic type give you the ability to reference in your code a type without having to specify it yet.

Comment: The types within the generic body are actually only known at compile time (rather than runtime), thanks to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: @augray "fixed" it, but it seems clunky. I'll see if I can find a better way to express it. Thanks for remining me generics were specified during compilation